# python regex match with string that has multiple spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string example:

```
'NAME: "test1",  DESCR: "AAA 1111S ABC 48 BB (4 BBBB) TEST1 "'
```

i am trying to extract out "AAA 1111S" but am struggling to know what i am doing wrong in the regex?

the regex i am using is below, i thought it would work based on the first space then 2nd space plus remaining chars in string.

```
^.+(AAA\s.+)\s.+"$
```

but it will only pull out the following:

AAA 1111S ABC 48 BB (4 BBBB) TEST1

Comment: can I ask is it always 3 letters, 4 numbers 1 letter?

Comment: if it is you could just use something like \"(\w{3}\s\d{4}\w)\s

Comment: multiple lines and desired results really help with regex

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use `(AAA\s.+)` where the `.+` will match any character 1+ times. That will match until the end of the string. The part that follows `\s.+"$` will match `TEST1 "`

You could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=")` to assert what is on the left is a double quote. Then match AAA followed by 1+ times a whitespace character `\s+` and 1+ times not a whitespace character `\S+`.

`(?<=")AAA\s+\S+`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KHAKAa/1)

If you want to keep the anchor ^ and match from the first occurrence of AAA, you could use `.+?` which will match any characters 1+ times non greedy.

`^.+?(AAA\s+\S+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lx8Emw/1)

Comment: I think you can have the same result without the lookbehind.

Comment: @AlexG That is true but in the example data there is another part that has 3 upper case characters. So I have used the positive lookbehind to be more specific where to match AAA.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'NAME: "test1",  DESCR: "AAA 1111S ABC 48 BB (4 BBBB) TEST1
>>> sol = re.findall('\w{3}\s\w{5}',string) 
>>> sol
['AAA 1111S']
```

Comment: \w is used for alphanumeric and i used {m} to give exact number of alphanumeric. Is that what you wanted? :) Please don't down-vote i did what I understand from your question language. If you wanted something else do comment.

Comment: you should write an explanation to your code. Just code answer's are not suggested.

Comment: so 1111S could be 111S or ABC , it could change over time but there will always be a space between 111S and ABC even if it was say "222S XYZ2" and also a space between AAA and 1111S